# Android:How to setSelection() in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Class which extends ListActivity, and is called by Activity_1.

ListActivity contains the listview with CheckedTextView.

When i select a row in listview, it should show a CheckedTextView and pass the data to Activity_1 and should remember the selected row.

The selected CheckedTextView should be shown when Activity_1 calls ListActivity again ?

Answer (score 0):

```
getListView().setSelection(int);
```

You could always pass the remembered item back to ListActivity when you call it again.